# Choose Your Own Adventure Books/Games: Are there any Two-Player variants?

Tags: game-recommendation

My fiance and I have recently been playing ["Destiny Quest"](http://smile.amazon.com/Legion-Shadow-DestinyQuest-Michael-Ward/dp/0575118733/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8), it had a module from online that allowed for multi-player. We adapted that to work in the story and fixed the loot/gold so it wouldn't give us an unfair advantage. It was a blast.

We've been on the search for more CYOA-style books that have two player, but they seem incredibly rare. We don't mind some table top styles (like the D&D 4th board games), but something preferable that can be played on the car or in bed, maybe with the use of a phone for simple dice rolls and stats.

Does anyone know of any? Or at least, any good ones that are easy to 'role-play' as two separate individuals (outside just being two people debating on the next choice)?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting something that has two equal players who both have characters, or something that has one player running the adventure and the other playing a character?

Comment: (Even with that clarification though, this [may be off topic for the site](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/are-the-fighting-fantasy-gamebooks-and-contents-on-or-off-topic). You might want to ask at Boardgames.SE.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie , I am not asking for a boardgame explicitly, an RPG book is fine (even simple modules for tabletop campaigns).

As far as the play itself, I was hoping to find more where two players are playing. They both have a character sheet, they both roll in combat, etc.

Comment: It's good that RPG-based answers are OK, since you're asking on an RPG site and we can't suggest anything else without breaking our own rules about staying on-topic. If you really do want to hear about options that might not be RPGs, that's part of why I suggested Boardgames.SE (which is more than boardgames, really) might be helpful also/instead.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Thanks for the heads up, the lack of answer is pretty telling. I will post this over there this week, and if I get something good (and something that can relate back to here) I will add a comment back to this post!

Answer (score 9):

The only thing I can think of is [Murderous Ghosts](http://theunstore.com/index.php/unstore/game/128), which is a two player game by Vincent Baker that feels very choose your own adventure. I think those books were an explicit inspiration for the game? The rulebook certainly follows a similar format, having pages with different numbers that you're prompted to read throughout the game by the choices that you make. One person kind of takes on a GM-ish role while the other plays the character exploring the haunted house. It uses a deck of cards instead of dice, so it would work fine to play in bed or the car. Here's a [link to a review](http://womenwriteaboutcomics.com/2014/10/30/scary-times-with-dice-murderous-ghosts-review/), if you're interested.

Comment: Awesome! While this isn't explicitly what I was looking for, this sounds like something along those lines. I really like the concept of the GM/Player for a two player experience.

Comment: @Vetre If you're interested in a GM+player two-player dynamic, you might want to check out the questions in our [[tag:one-on-one]] tag.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - Fantastic, I didn't know the [one-on-one] was an established tag. I will take a look there. Should I update my post to have the tag?

Comment: @Vetre The question as written focuses on a slightly different way of playing, and updating it might actually make it a duplicate of some other question. I'd leave this as-is to see what it gathers, but *also* browse that tag to see what other ideas interest you.

Answer (score 7):

While it's not a two-player "*choose your own adventure*" book, but more of a two-player "*Fighting Fantasy*" book, the Duelmasters book [Challenge of the Magi](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/14171/duel-master-1-challenge-magi) is quite similar. In it the players take the role of two wizards facing off in a duel-to-the-death across the planes.

All it requires is a die, and pen and paper to record items, spells, hitpoints and codewords.

I loved this pair of books as a kid, which can be testified to by the fact that my two books are literally falling apart at the spine. The books also contains guidelines for playing it single player.

From BoardGameGeek

> Similar in some regards to the Ace of Aces book series, Duel Master takes 2 players, each with their own book, into competition with one another. Play is paragraph based, with each player making their own choices about what they want their character to do.
>
> In "The Challenge of the Magi", each player takes on the role of a mage (specializing in one of five types or colors of magic), putting themselves forward as replacement for the recently deceased head of the council. Who shall rule is determined by ritual duel to the death in the Rainbow Land - a series of interconnected dimensions, each filled with its own denizens and incorporating its own magical laws.

There is apparently a whole series of these books (the Duelmaster series), which I have heard are all quite differnt to each other, but I have never managed to find a second one.

Having a look on BGG, there appear to be a few more:

- [Blood Valley](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/14172/duel-master-2-blood-valley), one player is a demonic hunter, the other is his prey.
- [The Shattered Realm](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/14173/duel-master-3-shattered-realm), each player is the leader of a kingdom, building up allies for a showdown between the two.
- [Arena of Death](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/16340/duel-master-4-arena-death), players are both gladiators in the arena.

Comment: Cool find, I'd heard of something like this, but hadn't seen it in person.
It seems there are four books in the series:
http://www.gamebooks.org/show_series.php?id=124

As for the others, I will keep looking. Some of the books in DuelMaster are quite expensive and seem like they cater to the collectors crowd.

Comment: @Vetre Yeah, they appear to be super rare, I have been looking for more of these since I was a kid. Though now that you have reminded me of them, I think I may need to go looking for them again ;)

Comment: I will have to add these to my list of "to find" books. Maybe we could email the publisher to see if they can release a digital version.
Quick research shows **Armada Publishing**, bit it seems they went out of business in the late 90's. I wonder who currently has the rights.

Comment: @Vetre I see what you mean. Most of them go for $60-70 on ebay, and thats just for 1 book. Though I did manage to pick up a copy of Shattered Realm book 1 for $7 :)

Comment: A co-worker and I ended up sending a few emails out to several groups that may own the rights to the non-hardy boys work of Armada Publishing. This ended up being Harper Collins, Del Ray, and a few others (Harper being the largest lead). Hopefully we get a response back for who has the rights, so we can push a digital release!
It would be incredibly pricey and time consuming to get some of these older collectors or hidden versions.

Answer (score 5):

I've had fun playing [D&D solo adventures for 4e](http://dnd.chromesphere.com/how_to_play.html) which provides for GMless adventures for solo play. Critically, however, it provides for a party size of *2*, and (so long as both players are happy with scripted interactions), provides for a series of fascinating decisions and tactical adventures using 4th edition. The adventures are embedded in the site, and I couldn't imagine playing it without characters built via DDI's character builder. The game takes you through to mid-heroic, which should provide sufficient impetus for quite a few nights of play.

Subsequent to that, most adventures and scenarios up on DDI can be abstracted to this style of "tactical puzzle" with nods towards role-playing, and in the long days of my PhD, I ran some solo games in exactly this vein. For that, however, both players will need to be able to run a total of 5 characters, but running characters as a joint tactical exercise can, itself, be fun.

Comment: Good call. We had started with Ravenloft (4th Ed) and moved to doing some other modules we found online. Sadly many of them seemed incomplete. This looks like a good solution, I will have to get the DDI and give this a go.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Project Aon](http://www.projectaon.org/en/Main/Books) has converted a lot of old CYOA books into digital format.  About halfway down the page they have a "Combat Heroes" section where you can find PDFs for the following.  The Black Baron and White Warlord books pair up for a head to head adventure with a friend, and the Emerald Enchanter and Scarlet Sorcerer books pair up for the same, or any of them can be played as Solo adventures.

Comment: Great find with Project Aon. It being free is a huge plus.

Answer (score 2):

I had a few of these type of books when I was growing up.

Some were competitive:

- Duel Master series
- Combat Heroes series
- [TSR's 1 on 1 series](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/5079/1-1-adventure-gamebooks)

Some were cooperative, with one book but multiple players/characters:

- [Blood Sword series](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/2585/blood-sword-gamebooks)

Comment: I'm digging the blood sword look, I just ordered it. Thanks for the heads up. As for the rest, I am adding them to my find list. 
For Duel Master, I've emailed the publishers who have bought out the original ones, I think all that's left is to email the Author himself and hope for a digital rerelease.