# Multiplayer Game Books like Fighting Fantasy

Tags: gm-less

I'm looking for game books that are similar to titles such as *Warlock of Firetop Mountain* or other Fighting Fantasy books except that they are meant for multiple players. Essentially, I'm looking for DM-less adventure books. Unfortunately, I can't find any examples on Amazon or anything like that. Other things I'd be interested in checking out are rules-light games that accomplish the same premise such as a cards-based DM-less RPG like Expedition: The RPG Card Game. I just don't know what's out there or how to find it. Any help you can offer is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the stack please take our [tour] to learn more about us and how we operate. You can also visit the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of recommendation question is not suitable for our format but we do provide a [list of forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9335/33707) where you might be able to ask this, including our own [chat]

Comment: While recommendation questions are now off-topic, there was a similar question asked when they were allowed: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57100/choose-your-own-adventure-books-games-are-there-any-two-player-variants